# Yii file include does not work, while i can access it by typing in URL

Tags: php, yii, include

I'm having an issue with an include/require.

I made a dir in my root file:

```
root/includes
root/includes/something.inc.php
```

Now i try to include/require that file into my webapp:

```
require(Yii::app()->baseurl.'/includes/something.inc.php');
```

But it says `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

When i go to `mydomain/includes/something.php` it just works.

Why o why can't I include/require this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii(1) offers multiple shortcuts to various paths. The most commonly used one are available as `Yii::app()->baseUrl` and `Yii::app()->basePath`.

Both shortcuts serve different purposes and act on a different level. `baseUrl` represents the url your application is available from on the web. And has it's use if you want to link assets and files by their *public* url. `basePath` acts on the filesystem level. Includes are almost ever done on the filesystem-level. This mismatch is  the cause of your problem.

Reference:

- [CApplication::$basePath](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#basePath-detail)
- [CApplication::$baseUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#getBaseUrl-detail)

Answer (score 1):

You try to instead:

```
require(Yii::app()->baseurl.'/includes/something.inc.php');
```

by:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/something.inc.php');
```