# Include PHP file in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to include a php file in yii framework but is not working, that's my code:

```
$url = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/new/x/x/x.php';
include $url;
```

I tried to use require and require_once but it gives error.

Comment: Whats the error? And whats the value of $url

Comment: you can use Yii::import('pathalias'.x.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../css/new/x/x/x.php';
include $url;
```

And for a more comprehensive analysis have a look at this: [Yii file include does not work, while i can access it by typing in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360276/yii-file-include-does-not-work-while-i-can-access-it-by-typing-in-url)

Answer (score 1):

First, why the PHP file is located inside the CSS folder?

If it is a helper, it could be located at protected/helpers folder. If it is a extension, it could be located at protected/extensions, and so on. I sugest you read http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/.

Once the file is in the correct place, you can use **Yii::import()** or **Yii::getPathOfAlias()** to include the file. This way you use *alias* instead of *paths*:

**1.Define an alias**. It could be done inside your entry script (index.php file):

```
define('COMMON_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/common');
Yii::setPathOfAlias('common', COMMON_PATH);
```

**2.Import or include the file.** If included file represent a class you can use *Yii::import("common.path.to.your.file.inside.common.folder.YourFile");* If included file has code to be executed use *Yii::getPathOfAlias()* and *include()*:

```
$folder = Yii::getPathOfAlias('common.path.to.your.file.inside.common.folder');
include($folder.'/file.php');
```

Comment: The `include` statement includes and evaluates the specified file. `Yii::import` only imports a class or a directory.

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2 replace app() with $app

```
$url = Yii::$app->basePath.'/../css/new/x/x/x.php';
include $url;
```